# Ubuntu 13.04: apt-get and check-new-release CPU bound

Tags: ubuntu, apt, cpu-usage

I own a virtual server hosted by a provider. A few hours ago I was notified about the VM being CPU-bound. I couldn't log in and rebooted the server. After the boot, apt-get and check-new-release were CPU bound. I've never seen such a problem related to those two executables. Searching around I've only found a few references of related bugs, but they are quite old. Does somebody know of some issue related to these executables?

Thanks.

Comment: Today I had the same problem on all of my digitalocean droplets.  See this post, but it didn't seem to help some of the users there http://askubuntu.com/questions/322343/check-new-release-process-eating-up-resources-on-ubuntu-server-13-04